# DAX New & Lost Customers Table

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to create a List for New Customers Added during the year and List of Lost Customers, I have written a DAX which works fine in summary count but doesn't work in table matrix.

```
    NTB =
VAR currentCustomers =
    VALUES ( Deposits[CIF ID] )
VAR currentDate =
    MAX ( Deposits[Source.Date] )
VAR pastCustomers =
    CALCULATETABLE (
        VALUES ( Deposits[CIF ID] ),
        ALL (
            Deposits[Source.Date].[Month],
            Deposits[Source.Date].[MonthNo],
            Deposits[Source.Date].[Year]
        ),
        Deposits[Source.Date] < currentDate
    )
VAR newCustomers =
    EXCEPT ( currentCustomers, pastCustomers )
RETURN
    COUNTROWS ( newCustomers )
```

[image]

Total Row is correct, even if I remove one function the table remains same..

Appreciate your help

Comment: What do you see with `RETURN COUNTROWS(pastCustomers)`? Then, what when you change `ALL()` to `ALL(Deposits[Source.Date])`?

Comment: @Amar are you sure about this ? ``VAR currentDate =
    MAX ( Deposits[Source.Date] )``

Comment: you have also ``New Customers Added during the year``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

Modelling --> Add Table

```
Table =
VAR _max =
    MAX ( Deposits[Source.Date] )
RETURN
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        SUMMARIZE ( Deposits, Deposits[CIF ID] ),
        "NTB",
            CALCULATE (
                COUNT ( Deposits[CIF ID] ),
                FILTER (
                    ALLEXCEPT ( Deposits, Deposits[CIF ID] ),
                    Deposits[Source.Date] >= _max
                )
            ),
        "Lost Customers",
            CALCULATE (
                COUNT ( Deposits[CIF ID] ),
                FILTER (
                    ALLEXCEPT ( Deposits, Deposits[CIF ID] ),
                    Deposits[Source.Date] < _max
                )
            )
    )
```

[image: try]

Comment: That's great. The problem is  why OP's measure doesn't result. It is looks ok, but seem that `pastCustomers` is empty in a matrix rows. And It's interesting - why.

Comment: @Mik The OP's code doesnt work in my sample data actually... [You can check here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14baHXBRNKxzxPy5oPENCPcHxoIntnYkB/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: This what I want to say - the code is not a problem, something with filters/slicer/matrix... Your code is good, but it may not help OP.

Comment: @Mik we can create solutions for the given information only...

Comment: Thank you for the great support. I guess the issue is with my filters which I got to know from your solution.

Comment: @Amar you are welcome anytime, you can tweak and adjust my code according to your requirements...

Comment: @Amar, but what filter influenced your measure? did you changed your measure?